# open network access to virtualbox guest from host only

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, firewall, nat

I have built a Debian virtual machine running in VirtualBox on a Linux Mint host.

I am confused about the choices for networking configuration.

I wish to achieve the following behavior:

1. Resolve host name of guest when queried on host (even though guest is not registered on external DNS or DHCP server).
2. Allow guest to access public internet services (e.g. web).
3. Allow host to access services running on guest (e.g. SSH) through hostname of guest.
4. Block access to services on guest originating outside the host.

As a matter not directly related to the virtualization system, I would like the SSH server to accept a login for any registered user without a password or key (which is sensible, since access from outside the host would be blocked).

Which configution settings should I choose for the results I have explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I have learned that support for such automation is not readily available directly through VirtualBox. Tools such as Vagrant and Libvirt are intended for such a higher level of automation, and support VirtualBox through drivers. These tools, however, also support other virtualization platforms, which may be preferable   over VirtualBox.

VirtualBox is more directly intended for  simple and manual management of guest machines.